# .Net Compact Framework, how to "use" it under windows (testing purposes)

Tags: windows, testing, compact-framework

I would like to use the .net compact framework under windows if there is any way (I don't want to pay to test my application for this framework branch).

Are there any possibility? (remember that compact-framework 2.0 is not the same of normal framework as optimization!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run it directly in Windows. But you can use the Windows Mobile emulators that come with Visual Studio to run and debug it.